# Using ByteBuddy Java agent without -javaagent argument

Tags: java, byte-buddy

I am trying to instrument some classes in a project. When I package the agent classes into a jar and use it via -javaagent  it works fine.

```
public static void premain(String arguments, Instrumentation instrumentation) {

        new AgentBuilder.Default()
                .type(ElementMatchers.nameStartsWith("com.cn."))
                .transform((builder, type, cl, m) -> builder
                        .method(ElementMatchers.isAnnotatedWith(Retryable.class))
                        .intercept(to(Retry.class)))
                .installOn(instrumentation);
    }
```

When I try to run it directly in the project the instrumentation fails sometimes. (I initialize bytebuddy in a static block of the test class).

```
    static {
        Instrumentation inst = ByteBuddyAgent.install();

        new AgentBuilder.Default()
                .type(ElementMatchers.nameStartsWith("com.cn."))
                .transform((builder, type, cl, m) -> builder
                        .method(ElementMatchers.isAnnotatedWith(Retryable.class))
                        .intercept(to(Retry.class)))
                .installOn(inst);
    }
```

For instance when I add this test, my code is no longer intercepted.
Doing the same with try/catch works.

```
RuntimeException e = Assertions.assertThrows(RuntimeException.class, () -> f.doit("doit foo"));
```

Is there a safe way to instrument classes in the same project without -javaagent?

Project is on OpenJdk11.

Comment: Have you tried adding a listener to the agent builder to see if the type in question is still discovered or if there is an error? Did you check if the installation in the block throws an exception?

Answer (score 0):

Using the -javaagent option you'll always be sure that your classes are loaded after the agent has been installed.

If you install the agent in a static block you have to assure that this piece of code is executed before any classes you want to instrument are loaded. Eg. you could install the agent in your main method or in a static block where the main method resides as well.

Comment: I checked if the Foo class is loaded after the test class (system.out in static block). It was loaded later. The strange thing is that the "Assertions.assertThrows" usage caused the problem...  How do all the libraries like Hibernate, Mockito etc solve this problem? I never used an app with -javaagent but they all use Instrumentation.

Comment: Mockito and Hibernate use well-defined life cycles, Mockito for example uses retransformation if using the inline mock maker where any mocked type is retransformed explicitly.